# How to create criteria for all instances ordered by relationships count (one to many)?

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, grails, criteria

I have a domain class Person in a one-to-many relationship with Childs. A Person can have many childs and a child has only one Person.

```
class Person {
 static hasMany = [childs: Child]
}

class Child {
Person person
}
```

Now i want to get a list of **all persons ordered by child count**. How should the Criteria look like? I'm using the grails mongodb plugin wich supports gorm/hibernate criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
def sortPerson = Person.sort{it.childs.count}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround i'm using, but i would like to have this on database layer.

Comment: Any particular reason to do sorting on database layer? I prefer to avoid operations on database as much as I can.

Comment: It's depending on your database system. It's mostly faster than sorting by yourself and while handling with big data you can save ram.